# Installing binary package on heroku

Tags: build, heroku, build-process

I want to deploy a binary package on heroku for use by my application

I am using the new Cedar stack, the official documentation states that it is recommended to use the vulcan tool for building binaries for heroku

So , i just did that, and the result was a tar.gz file containing a mini linux file system

Now what? how to deploy that binary package to heroku?

all the available documentation refer to using vulcan with buildpacks to create new applications

but, i want to deploy this binary package to an existing application

The question is , How can i do that?
should i put it in my git repo and upload it? if so, where should i put it? and how to unpack it and deploy it correctly on heroku to be available  and correctly configured?

thanks

Joe

Comment: it is a precompiled package....

Answer (score 3):

You need to incorporate that compiled output into a buildpack.  See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries

Start with the buildpack for the language you're working in -- ruby / python / node.  You'll probably just unpack the tarball into the a subdirectory of the `vendor` directory in the buildpack.  Push your forked buildpack up to github and then point heroku to the buildpack.